# Treeview not showing data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have been trying to reproduce this example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

For some reason my treeview isn't showing any data at all and I can't figure out why (I get no errors and don't really know how to debug this decently). This is my code:

MainWindow.XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Tryout.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tryout.domain"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<TreeView Name="treeViewFiles" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,12" Width="200" ClipToBounds="True">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Directory}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType ="{x:Type local:File}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

MainWindow.XAML.cs

```
namespace Tryout
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Directory rootDirectory = new Directory("Root");
            rootDirectory.Children.Add(new Directory("Subdirectory 1"));
            rootDirectory.Children.Add(new Directory("Subdirectory 2"));
            ((Directory)rootDirectory.Children[1]).Children.Add(new File("The only file"));

            treeViewFiles.ItemsSource = rootDirectory.Children;
        }
    }
}
```

File.cs

```
namespace Tryout.domain
{
    public class File : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name;

        public File(String _name)
        {
            Name = _name;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Directory.cs

```
namespace Tryout.domain
{
    public class Directory : File
    {
        public List<File> Children = new List<File>();

        public Directory(String _name) : base(_name) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `File` and `Directory` classes expose their data through fields, not properties, and you can't bind to fields. Change public fields `Name` and `Children` to properties and your code will work.

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem. Didn't know there actually was a difference between fields and properties. Think I should read some more about C#.